# При просмотре ютуб в полноэкраном режиме виден футер, хотя свойство z-index у футера меньше, как исправить этот баг?

Tags: css

При просмотре ютуб в полноэкраном режиме виден футер, хотя свойство  z-index у футера меньше, как исправить этот баг?
Вот как вставляется плеер:

```
<iframe width="560" height="504" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/111111" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Футер фиксированый.

Comment: z-index может не зарешать если родительские контексты перекрываются. то есть у детей будет так: iframe(z-index:1000), footer(z-index:1) и футер в определенных обстоятельствах все равно может быть выше. тут нужно смотреть комплексно верстку. пройдись по дом дереву вверх и проверь на каком из родителей происходит не правильное перекрывание, после чего от этого и пляши. ну альтернатива убрать футер js при фулскрине, но это как то тупо.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую